# MDL - popup snackbar on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, razor, material-design-lite

I am using material design light, from google, and jquery.
I cannot seem to get the snackbar to show on pageload. The error that I am 
getting is

index.cshtml (extract)

```
<div id="demo-toast-example" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar mdl-color--accent">
        <div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>
        <button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button" style="display:none;"></button>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var ErrorStringValue = '@ViewBag.ErrorText';
        if (ErrorStringValue.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(addSnackbar(ErrorStringValue), 2000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

scripts.js

```
function addSnackbar(string) {
    var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#demo-toast-example');
    var data = { message: string, timeout: 2000 };
    snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
}
```

The error that I have had is that when loading the page with an errortext viewbag, it will excecute the addSnackbar **immediately**, and then the snackbarConatiner.MaterialSnackbar will be null

I had tried to delay it to give other stuff time to load? But as you can see but for some reason it does not actually wait for the delay to be over before excecuting the function addSnackbar()

I presume there is some element of mdl that gets setup after document.ready but how can I set the snackbar going after that is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been misunderstanding how the jquery document.ready works. It will excecute once the page has finished rendering, but will not wait for js libraries to be finished. In this case, the material.js had not finished loading. So I replaced the script in index.cshtml with the following

```
<script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            var ErrorStringValue = '@ViewBag.ErrorText';
            if (ErrorStringValue.length > 0) {
                addSnackbar(ErrorStringValue);
            }
        });
</script>
```

This worked fine. Window.load event will fire after all libraries are finished loading as well.

Comment: I was developing in chrome and firefox at the time, so it should have worked. What's the specific problem you're seeing?

Comment: I still get the exception on undefined. I followed this to replace the onload event of the window object and it's working : https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1995#issuecomment-217389362

Comment: I suppose its possible that loading some other library in my solution had caused the small delay recommended there. Good link though

Comment: With jQuery 3.0 this needs to be changed to 

`$(window).on('load', function () {`

because .load() no longer exists.